# Accessing the next element in list to compare in Scala

Tags: list, scala

I'm new to Scala and i was wondering how you can call the next element of the list because I am trying to compare the current element with the adjacent one. 
Given x as the current element, I tried similar to java, x+1 but that didnt work. Any help?

```
for (x <- list; if (x == (next adj. element))) println("same")
```

Comment: Please post some code. If x is the (value of) the current element then x+1 isn't going to be the next element in Java either. If it's the index of the next element, then things should work.

Comment: Please accept an answer, people spent time trying to help you... at least give them fake internet points

Answer (score 40):

How about sliding?

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4)
list.sliding(2).foreach(println)

//List(1, 2)
//List(2, 3)
//List(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 8):

The canonical ways to do this in a `for` loop would be:

```
scala> val xs = List(1,2,3,4,3,2)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2)

scala> for (List(left,right) <- xs.sliding(2) if (left < right)) println(left + " < " + right)
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4

scala> for ((left,right) <- (xs zip xs.tail) if (left < right)) println(left + " < " + right)
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4
```

(Incidentally, you're probably better off putting the if statement outside rather than inside the for comprehension in this example.)

If you have indices instead of values, you just dereference them using the same pattern.  Personally, I don't find this pattern very clear or useful.  It's slow, has weird corner-cases with lists that aren't full, and it's hard to follow what's going on.  Instead, I define

```
class PairedIterable[A](it: Iterable[A]) {
  def foreachpair(f: (A,A) => Unit) = {
    val i = it.iterator
    if (i.hasNext) {
      var prev = i.next
      while (!ans && i.hasNext) {
        val x = i.next
        f(prev,x)
        prev = x
      }
    }
  }
}
implicit def iterable_has_pairs[A](it: Iterable[A]) = new PairedIterable(it)
```

which can then be used like so:

```
scala> xs.foreachpair((left, right) => if (left < right) println(left + " < " + right))
1 < 2
2 < 3
3 < 4
```

Variants "forallpair", "existspair", and "findpair" are particularly useful.

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> val xs = 1::3::5::4::Nil
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 5, 4)

scala> (xs, xs.tail).zip.foreach(println)
(1,3)
(3,5)
(5,4)

scala>
```

Answer (score 3):

As an option you may use `match` and recursion instead of `for`:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = List(1, 5, 3)
    loop(list)
  }

  def loop(list: List[Int]) {
    list match {
      case Nil => println("Empty list")
      case x :: Nil => println("last " + x)
      case x :: tail => {
        println(x + " - " + tail.head)
        loop(tail)
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can even do `case head :: second :: rest => ...`

Answer (score 3):

This would be better handled by recursing over the *list*, instead of iterating through the *elements*, since elements don't know anything about the list.

For example:

```
def recurse[T](list: List[T]): Unit = list match {
    case List(x, y, _*) if x == y => 
        println("same")
        recurse(list.tail)
    case Nil =>
    case _   => recurse(list.tail)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As in Scala 2.11.7 the following are valid:

```
scala> val xs = List(1,2,3,4)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

1) Zip the tail

```
scala> xs.zip(xs.tail)
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (2,3), (3,4))
```

2) Slide the window

```
scala> xs.sliding(2)
res1: Iterator[List[Int]] = non-empty iterator
```

Answer (score -1):

```
scala> val li = List (3, 4, 5) 
li: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5)

scala> li.tail.head 
res74: Int = 4
```

If you don't want to compare just a single element, but a sequence of arbitrary length, you can do it in recursive function:

```
def compAdjectent (l: List [Int]) : Boolean = l match {
  case Nil => false 
  case x :: Nil => false 
  case x :: y :: xs => if (x.equals (y)) true else compAdjectent (y :: xs)
}
```

Comment: but im trying to iterate over the list with a for loop. i dont see how that would work. like for (l <- li; if (l != l+1))....

Comment: @Dan The subliminal message is that you are doing it wrong. :-)

Answer (score -1):

list.tail.head

gives the next element if you want to go through all the elements from the front of the list. This is because the head is the front-most element and tail is the rest of the list.